# Maximal operator inequality $P^*$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, convolution, harmonic-functions

The maximal operator function $P^*$ is defined in this way:

DEF: If $f\in L^{p}(\mathbb{T})$, $P^*f(x)=sup_{0<r<1}|P_{r}*f(x)|$.Where $P_{r}(t)=\sum_{I=-\infty}^{\infty}r^{|i|}\phi_{i}(t)$ is the kernel of Poisson.

But now, with this maximal operator, is possible to demonstrate that, for $1\le p<\infty$, there is a constant $c_{p}>0$ such that, for all $f\in L^p(\mathbb{T})$:

$||P^*f||_{p}\le c_{p}||f||_{p}$?

Thanks.

Comment: What is $P_r{}$?

Comment: Sorry I edit the question!

Comment: Yes. In fact if $M$ is the Hardy-Littelwood maximal function it's more or  less clear that $|P^*f|\le M|f|$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich so I have to prove it using Hardy-Littelwood maximal function?

Comment: Oh - just noticed a typo. Should be $1<p\le\infty$.

Comment: No, I'm sure that it's right $1\le p<\infty$

Comment: I am confused. Your question still does not explain what $P_r$ is.

Comment: You're entitled to your opinion. The inequality is trivial for $p=\infty$,  and if $f=\chi_{[0,1]}$ then $P^*f\notin L^1$.

Comment: I'm so sorry! $P_{r}$ is the Poisson kernel $ P_{r}(t)=\sum_{I=-\infty}^{\infty} r^{|i|}φ_{i}(t)$

Comment: @PhoemueX I've edit the question!

Comment: I think it is explained in Rudin, W. *Real and Complex Analysis*, or perhaps in Stein and Weiss *Introduction to Fourier Analysis on Euclidean Spaces*.